# Google Maps Infobox - Click on android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infobox

I have a small app that use google maps and Infobox set on a series of markers. Once you click on a infobox  image you go to another link. This works perfectly on Pc and my Ipad but the link is not "active" when you tap the image in Android (a Samsung phone) . Here are the some pieces of the code:

```
 var myOptions = {
                  content: boxText
                  ,disableAutoPan: true
                  ,maxWidth: infobox_width
                  ,boxClass:"mybox"
                  ,zIndex: null         
                  ,closeBoxMargin: "-13px 0px 0px 0px"
                  ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                  ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                  ,isHidden: false
                  ,pane: "floatPane"
                  ,enableEventPropagation: true
          };             
  infoBox = new InfoBox(myOptions);      

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
 var beach = locations[i];
 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng,
     map: map,
     shadow: shadow,
     icon: custompin(beach[8]),
     shape: shape,
     title: beach[0],
     zIndex: beach[3],
     image:beach[4],
     price:beach[5],
     type:beach[6],
     type2:beach[7],
     link:beach[9],
     infoWindowIndex : i
 });

  gmarkers.push(marker);



     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

       infoBox.setContent('<div class="info_details" id="strut"><a href="'+this.link+'">'+this.image+'</a> <h2><a href="'+this.link+'">'+this.title+'</a></h2> <div class="prop_details"><span class="info_inside">'+this.type+' for '+this.type2+' - '+this.price+'</span></div>' );
     infoBox.open(map, this);    
     map.setCenter(this.position);   
     if(infobox_width==700){
            map.panBy(380,-190);
     }else{
             map.panBy(0,-190);
            }

  });
```

I also tried listing the the domready event for infobox but with no luck :

```
             google.maps.event.addListener(infoBox,'domready',function(){  
                 jQuery('#strut').click(function(){ alert('clicked!') }); 

          });
```

Comment: anyone ? any ideas ? :)

Comment: I also tried listing the the domready event for infobox but with no luck                      google.maps.event.addListener(infoBox,'domready',function(){
            jQuery('#strut').click(function(){
                alert('clicked!')               
            });
          
          });